# Get an API URL by route name in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5

Is there a way to specify the prefix when getting a route URL by its name in Laravel 5.5? For example,

In `routes/web.php`

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController', ['only' => 'index', 'create', 'edit']);
```

In `routes/api.php`

```
Routes::resource('users', 'UserController', ['only' => 'index', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']);
```

Both routes to the index methods have the name `users.index`, as confirmed when calling `php artisan route:list`. However, the URL for the web route is `/users` and the URL for the api route is `/api/users`.

To get the web route URL, I can do `route('users.index')`. Is there a way to get the URL for the api route using the route name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `routes/api.php`, wrap all routes with the prefix `api`:

```
Route::name('api.')->group(function () {
  ...
});
```

Then in `RouteServiceProvider`,

```
Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace.'\Api')
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Comment: The name can go in the `RouteServiceProvider` so the wrapper in `routes/api.php` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the resource controller's routes a prefix via the `as` option:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController', [
    'as' => 'your.prefix',
    'only' => ['index', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I know that I can give custom names, but I was looking for a solution without changing the API at all.

Comment: Hello. Spotted an error in answer which gave me headache for some time :)  Please correct it: `'only' => ['index', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']`